# Representing 2D data optimized by row vs by column vs flat

Tags: data-structures, d3.js

In D3 I need to visualize loading lab samples into plastic 2D plates of 8 rows x 12 columns or similar. **Sometimes I load a row at a time, sometimes a column at a time**, occasionally I load flat 1D 0..95, or other orderings. **Should the base D3 data() structure nest rows in columns (or vice verse) or should I keep it one dimensional?**

Representing the data optimized for columns [columns[rows[]] makes code complex when loading by rows, and vice versa. Representing it flat [0..95] is universal but it requires calculating all row and column references for 2D modes. I'd rather reference all orderings out of a common base but so far it's a win-lose proposition. I lean toward 1D flat and doing the math. Is there a win-win? **Is there a way to parameterize or invert the ordering and have it optimized for both ways?**

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your case the best implementation would be an [Associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) (specifically, a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) implementation of it). Keys would be coordinates and values would be your stored data. Depending on your programming language you would need to handle keys in one way or another.

Example:

```
[0,0,0] -> someData(1,2,3,4,5)
[0,0,1] -> someData(4,2,4,6,2)
[0,0,2] -> someData(2,3,2,1,5)
```

Using a simple associative array would give you great insertion speeds and reading speeds, however code would become a mess if some complex selection of data blocks is required. In that case, using some database could be reasonable (though slower than a hashmap implementation of associative array). It would allow you to query some specific data in batches. For example, you could get whole row (or several rows) of data using one simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE x=1 AND y=2 ORDER BY z ASC
```

Or, let's say selecting a 2x2x2 cube from the middle of 3d data:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE x>=5 AND x <=6 AND y>=10 AND Y<=11 AND z >=3 AND z <=4 ORDER BY x ASC, y ASC, z ASC
```

**EDIT:**
On a second thought, if the size of the dimensions wont change during runtime - you should go with a 1-dimentional array using all the math yourself, as it is the fastest solution. If you try to initialize a 3-dimentional arrays as array of arrays of arrays, every read/write to an element would require 2 additional hops in memory to find the required address. However, writing some function like:

```
int pos(w,h, x,y,z) {return z*w*h+y*w+x;} //w,h - dimensions, x,y,z, - position
```

Would make it inlined by most compilers and pretty fast.